# accepts_nested_attributes_for and after_remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, accepts-nested-attributes-for

I have a model like so

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments,
            after_add: :soil,
            after_remove: :soil,
            dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :soiled_associations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true

  def soil(record)
    self.soiled_associations = [record]
  end
end
```

When I add a new `comment` in the view it adds the object to my `post.soiled_associations` attribute (BTW `soiled_associations` is my attempt to name a custom method that does something similar to Rails's `Dirty` class, but for associations).

However, when I delete a comment in my view nothing gets added to the `post.soiled_associations` attribute.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it is in something about how `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works (perhaps bypassing these callbacks) but can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Shouldn't soil be implmented something like `self.soiled_associations ||= []; self.soiled_associations.push(record)` instead of replacing the entire attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell you what you are doing wrong since you haven't shown what you're doing. But there are only a few ways to do it:

```rb
>> Post.new(comments_attributes: [{}]).soiled_associations
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f01e99a30c0 id: nil, post_id: nil>]

>> Post.create(comments_attributes: [{}]).soiled_associations
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f01e9a08fd8 id: 3, post_id: 2>]

>> post = Post.last
>> post.comments.destroy_all
>> post.soiled_associations
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f01e99867e0 id: 3, post_id: 2>]

>> Post.create(comments_attributes: [{}])
>> post = Post.last
>> post.update(comments_attributes: [{id: 4, _destroy: true}])
>> post.soiled_associations
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f01e99a5500 id: 4, post_id: 3>]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've provided more information, but your answer got me to a solution. Thank you.